# handling of orientation Changes(fragments) with mutiple backstack via NavigationMenu options

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-framelayout

I am working on UI which is having NavigationMenu with multilevel fragments. So here is view,i am trying to implement.

[image: This is image show app view, i am trying to implement]

So navigation menu have few options each leads to open a ListFragment in FrameLayout, which further opens a List. Same as Option 2.

So i manage to `add` fragment on Portrait Mode. and using `SHOW` and `HIDE` i open next fragments with in same Navigation Open. Even Switching between Navigation Options retains instance of fragment of previous Navigation Option.

But the moment i switch to Landsacpe Mode, it lose all fragment, just show Default Fragment which was loaded First time.

Reason i am using `SHOW` and `HIDE`, because i don't want to reload Fragment everytime.

Is there any way to retain fragments in FrameLayout while orientation change.

Link to sample APK is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gd7w7dp35m9bubw/test_app.apk?dl=0)

Comment: Did you set viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit ?

Comment: @Html Tosin ..its not about viewpager, actually i am trying to figure out way to maintain multiple backstack for each NavigationMenu option. After rotation it shows fragment which was added first..